# How to configure server.xml to run in Tomcat, without Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to run webapplications in a Tomcat server (and I am a rookie). When I use the Eclipse instalation, everithing goes fine. But, when I run Tomcat directly, context errors has been occouring (like default Tomcat's page showing, error getting requestDispatcher, etc).

I've changed the 'context' tag removing the 'source' statement, but the problems persist.

What else I have to do? Thanks...

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000882/cannot-start-tomcat-as-an-external-tool-within-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation ?   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/

Maybe confirm the version of Tomcat you are working with (in your question).

Download the Tomcat ZIP unzip it.  Drop your WAR in the webapps dir.   Maybe drop your JDBC Driver JARs (mysql/postgres/mssql) in the lib/ directory.

Now startup Tomcat (running windows service if you used EXE installer, or scripts in bin/ directory).  It should be found on 127.0.0.1:8080 and maybe other local IP addresses on the same port :8080.

Why do you think you need to mess around with the context.xml / server.xml ?  Are you working with a fresh ZIP extraction of tomcat ?

Your explaination of the actual problem is very poor.  Following the above instructions (and ignoring Eclipse) should get anyone up and running in a short time.

FWIW - Ensure you have shutdown the Tomcat instance that Eclipse has been running/managing before trying to start up the external Tomcat instance.  Since as a general rule only one application can bind to the network ports at a time, you can modify the ports by grep'ing the conf/*.xml for Port= and port= and replace 8080 and other such numbers with different value, such as pre-pending a '1' to the front to make 18080.

Comment: I think he means that on a fresh install of tomcat7 the server.xml is unedited (as it should be considering its best practice not to edit this server.xml file) but as soon as you add a tomcat7 server to eclipse and "configure" it for a project called "WebService", it edits the server.xml file with "<Context docBase="WebService" path="/WebService" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebService"/>".
Now I'm guessing he wants to deploy his app independent of Eclipse and is having problems.

Comment: After editing the server.xml of the unziped location of the original tomcat archive you should delete your Eclipse runtime instance (if you created one) and go through the Servers (view) -> New, dialog and wizards to re-create the tomcat instance.  Since the server.xml is only copied once (at the time of runtime creation) to the Eclipse managed location inside the workspace.